# Decide if a function is well-defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Hi I have a function $f:\mathbb{Z}_3\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6 \ ;\ f(\hat x)=\bar 2\bar x + \bar 3$. And I need to tell whether is well defined or not.
 I never understood the process of doing these kind of exercises. The only thing I know is that I need to pick two different elements from the same equivalence class of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and to prove that they are sent to the same element from $\mathbb{Z}_6$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For well definedness you need to show that if $x=y$, then $f(x)=f(y)$. I am not using the bar notation as it is difficult to type on my device.

So start with $x \equiv y \pmod{3}$ (that is both $x$ and $y$ are the representatives of the same equivalence class modulo $3$). Then consider
\begin{align*}
f(x) & \equiv 2x+3\\
& \equiv 2(y+3k)+3\\
& \equiv 2y+3 \pmod{6}\\
&=f(y).
\end{align*}
This shows the images of $x$ and $y$ belong to the same equivalence class modulo $6$, hence well-defined.